# How do I get the previous row in a repeater when using OnItemDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which creates a list of tasks ordered by date complete.

```
           <asp:Repeater ID="rptCompletedProjectTasks" OnItemDataBound="rptCompletedProjectTasks_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
               <HeaderTemplate>
                   <h3>Completed Tasks</h3> 
                    <table class="projTaskTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:100px">W/C</th>
                            <th style="width:450px">Description</th>
                            <th style="width:100px">Due</th>
                            <th style="width:100px">Completed</th>
                            <th style="width:50px">Var</th>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblWeek" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("description") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("deadline", "{0:d MMM yy}") %></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("completedDate", "{0:d MMM yy}") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("var") %></td>
                   </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to visually group the completed tasks by week, with the week commencing date in the left column of the first row of a group of tasks and nothing in the others until the week changes. i.e.

[image]

I'm trying to check the previous item's WeekCommencing value, and only update the lblWeek control if it is different to the previous row's value using OnItemDataBound:

```
protected void rptCompletedProjectTasks_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime weekCommencing = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);


            if ((e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header) && (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer))
            {

                Label completedDate = e.Item.FindControl("lblCompleted") as Label;
                Label lblWeekCommencing = e.Item.FindControl("lblWeek") as Label;


                DateTime completed = Convert.ToDateTime(completedDate.Text);

                if (completed != weekCommencing)
                {

                    lblWeekCommencing.Text = getWeekCommencing(completed).ToString("d MMM");

                }
                else
                {
                    lblWeekCommencing.Text = "";
                }
                weekCommencing = completed;
            }
```

The function I'm using to get the start day of the week is:

```
protected DateTime getWeekCommencing(DateTime date)
        {

            int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - date.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime monday = date.AddDays(delta);
            return monday;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to achieve this is using a private property on the page class.
you could create a property like `private DateTime currentWeek.` and you could initiate this property in  the page load, like you do in the start of the method with weekCommencing.

Than on each row data bound you could check is this row date is in the same week of the currentWeek variable, and if it is not you set the label text and set the currentWeek to this row week.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentWeek = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Good call! Worked. (This repeater is nested in another repeater, so I added something to reset the date after each table was created: if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
                {
                    weekCommencing = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                }

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use and check that is lastItem?

```
e.Item.ItemIndex
```